# How to resolve the strange type error in a recursive map with statically resolved type parameters? (pt. 2)

Tags: generics, static, f#, inline

I tried two variants on this and they both have the same problem.

```
type CudaScalar<'t> = CudaScalar of name: string with
    member t.Name = t |> fun (CudaScalar name) -> name

type TypePrinter<'t>() = class end

let inline print_type x =
    ((^T or ^in_) : (static member PrintType: TypePrinter< ^in_> -> string) x)

type TypePrinter with
    static member inline PrintType(_: TypePrinter<float32>) = "float32"
    static member inline PrintType(_: TypePrinter<int>) = "int"

type ArgsPrinter = ArgsPrinter
let inline print_arg x =
    let inline call (tok : ^T) = ((^T or ^in_) : (static member PrintArg: ArgsPrinter * ^in_ -> string) tok, x)
    call ArgsPrinter       

type ArgsPrinter with
    static member inline PrintArg(_: ArgsPrinter, t: CudaScalar< ^t>) = 
        [|print_type (TypePrinter< ^t>()); t.Name|] |> String.concat " "
```

---

```
type CudaScalar<'t> = CudaScalar of name: string with
    member t.Name = t |> fun (CudaScalar name) -> name

type TypePrinter = TypePrinter

let inline print_type x =
    let call (tok: ^T) = ((^T or ^in_) : (static member PrintType: TypePrinter * ^in_ -> string) tok, x)
    call TypePrinter

type TypePrinter with
    static member inline PrintType(_: TypePrinter,_: float32) = "float32"
    static member inline PrintType(_: TypePrinter,_ : int) = "int"

type ArgsPrinter = ArgsPrinter
let inline print_arg x =
    let inline call (tok : ^T) = ((^T or ^in_) : (static member PrintArg: ArgsPrinter * ^in_ -> string) tok, x)
    call ArgsPrinter       

type ArgsPrinter with
    static member inline PrintArg(_: ArgsPrinter, t: CudaScalar< ^t>) = 
        [|print_type Unchecked.defaultof< ^t>; t.Name|] |> String.concat " "
```

At first I got the exact same error as in the [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41807147/how-to-resolve-the-strange-type-error-in-a-recursive-map-with-statically-resolve), but after I removed:

```
static member inline PrintArg(_: ArgsPrinter, (x1, x2)) = 
    [|print_arg x1;print_arg x2|] |> String.concat ", "
static member inline PrintArg(_: ArgsPrinter, (x1, x2, x3)) = 
    [|print_arg x1;print_arg x2;print_arg x3|] |> String.concat ", "
```

I got this in the last 3 lines (for both variants):

```
Script1.fsx(16,34): error FS0193: Type constraint mismatch. The type 
    'in_    
is not compatible with type
    FSI_0002.CudaScalar<'a>    
The type ''in_' does not match the type 'FSI_0002.CudaScalar<'a>'
```

This surprised me as the error does not show up in Intellisense, but only when I try to run it in F# Interactive. I am unsure what to do here once again. I might be abusing the type system a bit too much, but I am determined to finish this Cuda compiler in the tagless style, one way or another. I need to it like this in order to propagate type information for later stages.

Edit: Gustavo's fix works, but when I go a bit further it breaks again.

```
type CudaScalar<'t> = CudaScalar of name: string with
    member t.Name = t |> fun (CudaScalar name) -> name
type CudaAr1D<'t> = CudaAr1D of CudaScalar<int> * name: string with
    member t.Name = t |> fun (CudaAr1D (_, name)) -> name

type TypePrinter<'t>() = class end

let inline print_type x =
    ((^T or ^in_) : (static member PrintType: TypePrinter< ^in_> -> string) x)

type TypePrinter with
    static member inline PrintType(_: TypePrinter<float32>) = "float32"
    static member inline PrintType(_: TypePrinter<int>) = "int"

type ArgsPrinter = ArgsPrinter with
    static member inline PrintArg(_: ArgsPrinter, t: CudaScalar< ^t>) = 
        [|print_type (TypePrinter< ^t>()); t.Name|] |> String.concat " "
    static member inline PrintArg(_: ArgsPrinter, t: CudaAr1D< ^t>) = 
        [|print_type (TypePrinter< ^t>()); "*"; t.Name|] |> String.concat " "

let inline print_arg x =
    let inline call (tok : ^T) = ((^T or ^in_) : (static member PrintArg: ArgsPrinter * ^in_ -> string) tok, x)
    call ArgsPrinter       

type ArgsPrinter with
    static member inline PrintArg(_: ArgsPrinter, (x1, x2)) = 
        [|print_arg x1;print_arg x2|] |> String.concat ", "
    static member inline PrintArg(_: ArgsPrinter, (x1, x2, x3)) = 
        [|print_arg x1;print_arg x2;print_arg x3|] |> String.concat ", "
```

Once again, in the last two lines I manifest the exact same error as in pt. 1 of this. What I am trying to do here is make a part of an embedded Cuda DSL. The reason why I am doing it like this instead of using DUs is because with DUs, I would have to make the interfaces as a separate part. If I do it like this, I will be able to write `cuda_map (fun x -> x*x)` and have it compile because the type information will be present. The above fragment in particular is supposed to print out the arguments for the kernel's method.

If this was Haskell I would be using typeclasses+HKTs+tagless style to do it, in Ocaml GADTs, but in F# the only realistic choice for me is to imitate the [finally tagless style](http://okmij.org/ftp/tagless-final/) using statically resolved type params, but I have not counted on there being compiler errors.

I intend to pass on this thread to the issue I opened as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understood your question/what are you trying to achieve.

I don't know why you inserted the function in the middle of the type, in your previous question it was necessary but here I don't think so.

If you write it in the natural order it compiles:

```
type CudaScalar<'t> = CudaScalar of name: string with
    member t.Name = t |> fun (CudaScalar name) -> name

type TypePrinter<'t>() = class end

let inline print_type x =
    ((^T or ^in_) : (static member PrintType: TypePrinter< ^in_> -> string) x)

type TypePrinter with
    static member inline PrintType(_: TypePrinter<float32>) = "float32"
    static member inline PrintType(_: TypePrinter<int>) = "int"

type ArgsPrinter = ArgsPrinter with
    static member inline PrintArg(_: ArgsPrinter, t: CudaScalar< ^t>) = 
        [|print_type (TypePrinter< ^t>()); t.Name|] |> String.concat " "

let inline print_arg x =
    let inline call (tok : ^T) = ((^T or ^in_) : (static member PrintArg: ArgsPrinter * ^in_ -> string) tok, x)
    call ArgsPrinter
```

Please let me know if I am missing something.

**EDIT**

After your attempt to add more overloads, try to add them like this:

```
type ArgsPrinter with
    static member inline PrintArg(_: ArgsPrinter, (x1, x2)) = 
        [|print_arg x1;print_arg x2|] |> String.concat ", "
type ArgsPrinter with
    static member inline PrintArg(_: ArgsPrinter, (x1, x2, x3)) = 
        [|print_arg x1;print_arg x2;print_arg x3|] |> String.concat ", "
```

I mean, 'extending' twice.

Comment: Yeah, thank you very much, I'd be lost without your expertise. Please see the edit. Your code indeed compiles, but adding a few extra members makes the thing break again. I am starting to think that this was not the right path to making a mini-compiler even if in theory F# should be capable of it. I am curious if you will be able to find a way around this.

Comment: Saw your edit. It is astonishing that this works. I tried extending the original code in this way and it also compiles.

Comment: Yes, but once again, I can't really explain you why. As you said, I have some expertise in workarounding these kind of inconsistencies in the overload resolution because it's been already many years contributing to [FSharpPlus](https://github.com/gmpl/FSharpPlus). If you are interested you can also contribute the library, by doing that you'll learn all these common workarounds and some more complicated ones. And you can possible share what you're trying to achieve with others.

Comment: Reporting to the F# guys is in theory the right approach, and you should do it, but I think it's unlikely they will fix these issues any time soon unless a contributor submit a fix. I think if I got time this year I will try to submit a redesign of the constraint solver to make it more consistent and thus more usable. But will need lot of time to do that.

Comment: I'll take that to heart. I do not have a good record of contributing to libraries; the last two times I did it, I just ended up doing a lot of churn because I was in over my head. It was beneficial to me as I learned quite a lot, but not so much for the libraries I was trying to contribute to. To be honest, I am still wavering whether to do this Cuda compiler and the ML library in F# or some other language (most likely Haskell). This is actually the 4th time I am doing this compiler - while the others worked, I was finding it impossible to make a good interface for them.

Comment: I'll try hanging in there for a while longer since you were kind enough to get me through this.

Comment: Well, in general if we join efforts it's better what we can achieve. You can start by opening an issue with your question, describing what you are trying to do, then I can also have a look at your library if you post a link. That way we can help each other.